# Django form not redirect after submit

Tags: python, html, django

So I made a form but after i clicked Submit button, it not redirected at all. I don't know if the form is actually submitted or not, because after i clicked submit, the url just added /submit, not even redirect to the right page.

Here's my views:

```
def submit_company_profile(request):
  if request.session['status'] == "employer":
    form = CompanyProfileEdit(request.POST or None)
    if(request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid()):
        company_creator_profile_id = request.session['profile_id']
        country = request.POST.get('country', False)
        province = request.POST.get('province', False)
        city = request.POST.get('city', False)
        company_name = request.POST.get('company_name', False)
        company_description = request.POST.get('company_description', False)
        company_website = request.POST.get('company_website', False)
        company_logo = request.POST.get('company_logo', False)

        query = Company.objects.filter(company_creator_profile_id=request.session['profile_id'])
        query_size = query.count()
        if query_size > 0:
            company = query[0]
            company.country = country
            company.province = province
            company.city = city
            company.company_name = company_name
            company.company_description = company_description
            company.company_website = company_website
            company.company_logo = company_logo
            company.save()
        else:
            Company.objects.create(
                company_creator_profile_id=request.session['profile_id'],
                country = country,
                province = province,
                city = city,
                company_name = company_name,
                company_description = company_description,
                company_website = company_website,
                company_logo = company_logo
            )
    return redirect(reverse('app_employer:company_profile'))
```

Here's my HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'app-employer:submit-company-profile' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in company_form %}
                    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                        {{field}}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
        <div class="upload">
          <p><strong>Upload your company logo</strong></p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button class="btn btn-block btn-default">Choose File</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="text-file-name">
                <p style="color:#999">No file chosen</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="btn-padding-form">
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md btn-block" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
```

The upload logo button can't be use yet. So i'm gonna submit form without uploading the logo.

Comment: Most likely your top condition does not fit.

Comment: i'm not sure, because i have a function to show this edit profile page, and it used the same condition as this form's first condition.

Comment: @Sara can you correct the indentation please.  I'm not sure if the first `if` statement is meant to be for the whole `def` or just the next line.

Comment: have you tried using inspect element to view the form action url?

Comment: This is the wrong way of using Django forms: You should use the forms's `cleaned_data` to create objects in the database, not the raw `request.POST` data (otherwise you open yourself to all kinds of security issues). Also you should handle the case that `form.is_valid() == False` which you're not here. Finally, the only two possible reasons you are not redirected are: your view isn't called (check your url patterns) or `session['status']` is not `"employer"`.